# Replacing/aliasing a file using Webpack

Tags: webpack

I am trying to use a very new third-party module in my project, which I installed using `npm`. The module was apparently developed on an OS with a case-insensitive file system, so it requires a file `injectable.js` whereas the actual file name is `Injectable.js`. This breaks the bundling process.

The developers of the module know of this issue. Meanwhile, I am trying to figure out how to use the module as it is. I am using Webpack for bundling my project.

The tree structure of the relevant part of my project is roughly this:

```
├──config
│     ├──webpack
│          ├──webpack.js
│
├──src
│   ├──client
│        ├──index.js
│
│
├──node_modules
│    ├──the module in question
│          ├── dist
│          │   ├── decorators
│          │   │   ├── providers
│          │   │         ├── Injectable.js
│          │   │
│          │   ├── index.js
|
├──gulpfile.js
```

The `index.js` file in the `node_modules/the module in question/dist` folder is requiring the file `Injectable.js` from the providers folder, but does so with the command `require('./decorators/providers/injectable');`

I would like to alias `./decorators/providers/injectable` in that `index.js` with `./decorators/providers/Injectable`.

Here is what I am doing in my webpack.js file:

```
resolve: {
        alias: {
            './decorators/providers/injectable': './decorators/providers/Injectable.js',
        },
}
```

But this still does not work; I am getting the error `Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./decorators/providers/injectable`

Could you please suggest how to replace one file name in a node module with another while bundling with Webpack?

UPDATE:

Here's webpack's config file:

```
var path = require('path');
var rucksack = require('rucksack-css')({
    fallbacks: true,
    autoprefixer: true
});
var precss = require('precss');
var csswring = require('csswring');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, '../../'),
    debug: false,
    entry: [
        './src/client/'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '../../public/assets/js'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel?stage=1'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader'
            },
            {test: /\.png$/, loader: 'file-loader'},
            {test: /\.gif$/, loader: 'file-loader'},
            {test: /\.jpe?g$/, loader: 'file-loader'},
            {test: /\.eot$/, loader: 'file-loader'},
            {test: /\.woff2?$/, loader: 'file-loader'},
            {test: /\.ttf$/, loader: 'file-loader'},
            {test: /\.svg$/, loader: 'file-loader'}
        ]
    },
    postcss: function () {
        return [rucksack, precss, csswring];
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
            /ng-forward\/dist\/decorators\/providers\/injectable\.js/,
            require.resolve('ng-forward/dist/decorators/providers/Injectable')
        )
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js']
    }
};
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [`webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/normal-module-replacement-plugin/):

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
    /ng-forward\/dist\/decorators\/providers\/injectable\.js/,
    require.resolve('ng-forward/dist/decorators/providers/Injectable')
  ),
],
```

Comment: Went ahead and tried that, but am still getting the error `ERROR in ./~/ng-forward/dist/index.js Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./decorators/providers/injectable in <blah-blah>/node_modules/ng-forward/dist
 @ ./~/ng-forward/dist/index.js 125:37-81

Comment: When you replace `require.resolve('...')` with `function() { console.log('called') }`, is "called" printed anywhere in your webpack output?

Comment: I actually tried to do that to see what is passed as an argument to this function. But it did not get called.

Comment: It does get called for me. Make sure your RegExp is correct. You could also pass a RegExp that matches all (`/.*/`) as well as a `function(request)`, and inspect `request.resource` manually to find the actual path of `injectable.js`. You could then edit the RegExp to correctly match it.

Comment: It's super weird, but even a regular expression that should match anything (`/.*/`) does not cause the function passed as a second argument to printo anything in the console. The relevant part of my webpack config is: `plugins: [
        new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
            /.*/, function(request) {console.log('CALLED!', request)}
        )
    ],
`. 
Can't imagine what is it that I am doing wrong.

Comment: Could you add your entire `webpack.config.js` file to your question? Perhaps the `plugins` field gets overwritten later?

Comment: Yep, I was overwriting the plugins in the general config in the production config :-) Now that I corrected that I am getting the error `TypeError: arguments[i].apply is not a function`. I added my general webpack config file to my question.

Comment: Ok, found and removed the cause of the TypeError, but now I'm back to square one: `ERROR in ./~/ng-forward/dist/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./decorators/providers/injectable in /home/andrey/development/vagrant/ehr-admin/node_modules/ng-forward/dist`. Will experiment with regular expressions.

Comment: Finally! The regex that finally did it was:  `new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /decorators\/providers\/injectable/,
        require.resolve('ng-forward/dist/decorators/providers/Injectable')
)`. The bundle got assembled successfully. Thank you so much!

Comment: This have worked to me, thanks! BUT.... why the `resolve.alias` approach do not work? (I have spent a lot of time with it before search and found your solution). At first glance it look much more obvious than the plugin method.

Comment: It seems webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin is no longer available with NativeScript :(
I ended here just looking for alternatives.