# Mock library with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, mocking, webpack-4

I'm attempting to replace a library for testing.

The code I want to change:

```js
import foo from 'foo-lib'; // foo-lib is a library dependency in package.json
```

I want this to import src/mock-foo.js instead.

This is for end-to-end tests, so I can't use something like Jest mocks.

I have a development-only webpack.config. In that I've tried:

```js
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'foo-lib': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/mock-foo.js')
    },
    extensions: ['.js'], // need this for some other aliases (not shown)
  },
```

I've also tried the older technique in the `plugins` array:

```js
  new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
    /foo-lib/,
    'mock-foo.js'
  ),
```

as well as several variations on these.

I don't get errors, but the original library loads every time.

Is this even possible? If so, what's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any problems with your syntax. However, you might have some other clause in your webpack config that might be interfering. Can you post the entire webpack config file?

In my case, I used the same syntax except that I had the module specified in `externals`, which took precedence over `alias`. Removing the module from `externals` resolved my issue.

Comment: Sorry, I no longer have access to the full config. Hopefully your answer will help someone else; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I've found one solution based on [Replacing/aliasing a file using Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33481883/replacing-aliasing-a-file-using-webpack) .

Testing with the `is-number` library (just for a simple example), this works:

```js
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
      /is-number/,
      require.resolve('./src/mock.js')
    ),
  ],
```

As one of the commenters on the other post mentioned, it's not clear why the `resolve.alias` approach didn't work.

Comment: I'm 100% open to accepting better answers.